# Customising TOC of Bergen theme in Beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, vspace

I am creating a presentation using `Bergen` theme. Following is my TOC page. The `sidebar` contains the `section`s and the main text area contains the `subsection`s.

[image]

I have a couple of more sections to insert. To fit the entire TOC in the single slide, I want to achieve the followings:

1. The first `subsection` for each `section` should feature in the same line. (Now it is starting in the next line after the `section` in the `sidebar`.)
2. Need to control the `\vspace` between the sections and the subsections.

Following is an MWE. Please help.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{Bergen}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Overview}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
\section{Highlights of the year}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\section{Profile of the College}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\subsection{Management Structure}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\subsection{Student Strength}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\subsection{Faculty Strength}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\section{NBU Examination Results}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\subsection{Even Semester Examination -- July 2021}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\subsection{Odd Semester Examination -- February 2022}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\section{Students' Achievements}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move each first subsection up by one `\baselineskip` with the following patch (for cases where this isn't enough, like the two line section, you can manually tweak it with `\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}`):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{Bergen}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@subsection}{%
  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
}{%
  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
  \ifnum\the\c@subsection=1
      \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}%
  \fi
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Overview}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
\section{Highlights of the year}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\section{Profile of the College}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\subsection{Management Structure}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\subsection{Student Strength}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\subsection{Faculty Strength}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\section{NBU Examination Results}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}%
\subsection{Even Semester Examination -- July 2021}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\subsection{Odd Semester Examination -- February 2022}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\section{Students' Achievements}
\begin{frame}
    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]